# Why exporting reports to CSV/Excel?

Tags: report

I'm developing a web platform that will show data tables and charts using highchart.
Besides there is an exporting function for user to download csv/excel file.

But i'm thinking why I should make this. It's likely that exporting csv or excel is the standard. But is there any advantage?

I think I can export html file instead and the page will be interactive and much better than excel file. Is there anyone have idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV allows the user greater control over how they display the data - you may see some great visualisations from your users if you give them access to these.

Likely, the people who will actually use the CSVs (which will be a small percentage) would scrape the data anyway - so offering them up saves bandwidth and increases the happiness of your userbase because they don't have to go through the effort of writing a scraper.

It all depends on the type of data, though.

Comment: Swadq, thanks for your answer, that's useful to me.